# How do I mock a file open for a specific path in python?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest

So I know that in my unit test I can mock a context manager open(), i.e.:

```
with open('file_path', 'r') as stats:
```

mocked with

```
with mock.patch('builtins.open', mock.mock_open(read_data=mock_json)):
```

but is there a way for me to only mock it for a specific file path?  Or maybe some other way to ensure that the context manager gets called with the correct path in a unit test?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To mock `open` only for a specific path, you have to provide your own mock object that handles `open` differently, depending on the path. Assuming we have some function:

```py
def do_open(path):
    with open(path, "r") as f:
        return f.read()
```

where `open` shall be mocked to return a file with the content "bar" if `path` is "foo", but otherwise just work as usual, you could do something like this:

```py
from unittest import mock
from my_module.do_open import do_open

builtin_open = open  # save the unpatched version

def mock_open(*args, **kwargs):
    if args[0] == "foo":
        # mocked open for path "foo"
        return mock.mock_open(read_data="bar")(*args, **kwargs)
    # unpatched version for every other path
    return builtin_open(*args, **kwargs)

@mock.patch("builtins.open", mock_open)
def test_open():
    assert do_open("foo") == "bar"
    assert do_open(__file__) != "bar"
```

If you don't want to save the original `open` in a global variable, you could also wrap that into a class:

```py
class MockOpen:
    builtin_open = open

    def open(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if args[0] == "foo":
            return mock.mock_open(read_data="bar")(*args, **kwargs)
        return self.builtin_open(*args, **kwargs)

@mock.patch("builtins.open", MockOpen().open)
def test_open():
    ...
```

Comment: If you mock the open only in a module that you're testing (i.e. @mock.patch("module.open" mock_open), then no need to store builtin_open. I'd prefer to be more precise on what you're mocking

Comment: This code works great, but how can `assert_called` be used in this example? In case the tested function does not return a value from the mocked file.

Comment: You can't out of the box, because for all arguments except your specific one the buildin open is called. If you need this, you have to add this (e.g. record the call) to `MockOpen` yourself.