# mock a specific file with mock_open in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, mocking, pytest

I use this code snippet (From: [How do I mock a file open for a specific path in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69670597/how-do-i-mock-a-file-open-for-a-specific-path-in-python))

```py
builtin_open = open
def my_mock_open(*args, **kwargs):
    if args[0] == "myFile":
        # mocked open for path "myFile"
        return mock.mock_open()(*args, **kwargs)
    # unpatched version for every other path
    return builtin_open(*args, **kwargs)

def test_myfunc(mocker):
    mocker.patch('builtins.open', my_mock_open)
    myfunc()
```

This works well in that it only mocks the call to `myFile` and no other files that `myfunc()` reads from.
But I also want to assert that the correct data was attempted to be written to the file `myFile`.
I have tried to put the mock in a context "with as" statement but that didn't work.

`AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute assert_called_with`

Answer (score 0):

I got a bit further now.

Changed the decorator to
`@mock.patch("builtins.open", side_effect=my_mock_open)`

Then added an argument to the parameters of the test function
`def test_myfunc(open_mock, mocker):`

Then I can do for example
`assert open_mock.call_count == 1`